# Cannot get JDBC Connection in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i want to deploy my application in AWS.
i have setup my env.
and in root-context.xml of my application i have setup data source.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydbinstance.cnn31xputfwg.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1521:orcl" />
    <property name="username" value="myid" />
    <property name="password" value="mypassword" />
</bean>
```

this setting works fine locally in tomcat server.
but in AWS, it throws this error message

```
nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
Error querying database. Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
The error may exist in file [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/mappers/emp/emp-mapper.xml]
The error may involve EmpDAO.List ### The error occurred while executing a query
Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
```

Now my question is: what should i do to use get jdbc connection in AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like when you run the app on AWS it lacks Oracle JDBC driver in its `CLASSPATH`. So the answer is to add the driver to the classpath.

And I foresee the next question: "how to do this?", and simplest way is just to copy the driver to your classpath manually.

If you don't like manual work, you can generate Spring application template using [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/). Its build script has `org.springframework.boot` plugin, which does two important things:

- builds single `jar` file which includes Tomcat, so the application can be started just by `java -jar my-app.jar` (avoiding deployment to tomcat)
- includes all dependencies from build-script `dependencies` section to this `jar` file (including Oracle JDBC driver)

Comment: classpath? where can i find classpath? i'm using maven spring project and ojdbc.jar file exist in repository.